# Pipelight not working with firefox or chrome

Tags: wine, pipelight

I installed pipelight by following the instructions on the [website](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) but it still does not work properly .

Kernel version 
3.8.0-27-generic

When launching chrome the logs show up as . Can someone tell me what is wrong with my setup ?

```
n-linux:~$ google-chrome &
[1] 31528
husain@husain-linux:~$ ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[13:21:1005/131424:ERROR:platform_thread_linux.cc(99)] Failed to set nice value of thread to -10
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/home/husain/.config/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/pipelight'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] basicplugin.c:385:checkGraphicDriver(): GPU driver check - Your driver is supported, hardware acceleration enabled.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] using wine prefix directory /home/husain/.wine-pipelight/.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN] checking Silverlight installation - this might take some time.
wine-silverlight5.1-installer is already installed in /home/husain/.wine-pipelight/.
wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in /home/husain/.wine-pipelight/.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
[PIPELIGHT:WIN] windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN] embedded mode   is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN] usermode Timer  is off.
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x2b1f87, 0x350118, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x63f628, (null), (null), 0x350118,): stub
[PIPELIGHT:WIN] init successful!
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs looks similar to my. The difference is that I received more info at the end:

```
err:module:import_dll Loading library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\usr\share\pipelight\pluginloader.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\usr\share\pipelight\pluginloader.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\usr\share\pipelight\pluginloader.exe" failed, status c0000135
[PIPELIGHT] Error during the initialization of the wine process - aborting
```

If you have similar problem, you can solve it by linking missing dll's in wine-pipelight installation:

```
ln -s <path-to-your-crosscompiler-gcc-libs>/*.dll ~/.wine-pipelight/drive_c/windows/system32/
```

In my case (gentoo linux) needed libs are located in `/usr/lib64/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/`. If you don't know where to find dll's you can use:

```
locate libstdc++-6.dll.
```

Answer (score 2):

the instructions you used are a bit incomplete, as one important step is missing. The installation of Pipelight itself looks okay so far, but you probably don't have installed a user agent switcher. This is required to make the (streaming) pages think that you're using a Windows PC, otherwise they will refuse access or hang at 100% loading.

The following FAQ entry describes how to do this for Chrome/Firefox/Uzbl:
https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faq/2351

Comment: You saved my installation, I'm paying an online tv and couldn't use it. I had tried reinstalling spipelight everal time, giving me a 6002 error... all all I had to do was this! God bless you :D

Comment: What I can't understand is wtf are they requiring to use windows omg

Answer (score 0):

Remove and get the latest version from their official website,
 [fds-team.com](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html)

[image]

there's a bit different from previous version and please read carefully on the instruction given. [website](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) is outdated.